# Is it Possible to synthesize NSStrings for calculation?

Tags: objective-c, ios

-When I call-in my strings the data is not computing and I receive errors. Is it my coding (as seen below)? Is it possible to have 3 fields of data and the ans be the sum of the lowest 2 integers of the 3? This is killing my brain. (I've declared the optional integers for `X,Y,Z`) HELP! Thank you.

-(I'm synthesizing 2 separate `TextFields` (last,second,&third) and the same goes for labels and strings. I am also synthesizing the final field where the calculation should appear and that is `totalTextField, totalLabel, totalString`).

```
#import "EquationViewController.h"

@implementation EquationViewController

@synthesize lastTextField, lastLabel, lastString;
@synthesize secondLastTextField, secondLastLabel, secondLastString;
@synthesize thirdLastTextField, thirdLastLabel, thirdLastString;
@synthesize totalTextField, totalLabel, totalString;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        lastLabel.text = lastString;
        secondLastLabel.text = secondLastString;
        thirdLastLabel.text = thirdLastString;
}

    - (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL) animated
{
}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  lastLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Last", lastTextField.text];
    secondLastLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"2nd Last", secondLastTextField.text];
    thirdLastLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"3rd Last", thirdLastTextField.text];
    totalLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Total", totalTextField.text];


#include <stdio.h>
    int main ();
    {   
        double X,Y,Z,ans;
        X = 3;
        Y = 1.5;
        Z = 99;

        ans = (X+Y+Z) - MAX(X,MAX(Y,Z));
```

Comment: Maybe you made some errors in copying your code... I don't see interaction between the textFields/labels and the numbers. Besides, why are you defining a main here?

Comment: @Saphrosit - I believe my issue is defining the interaction between the texFields/Labels...I can't figure it out. As for defining a main, I was under the impression to allow for true integers it was a must. I then declared the other variables (X,Y,Z) to assign numeric values. Can you point me in the right direction or assist in any way? Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I got the problem you'd like to have the sum of the lowest two integer printed out (I didn't understand if in a textField or in a label).
These three numbers should be set by the user in `lastTextField`,`secondTextField` and `thirdTextField`. 
If this is correct (and the delegate is set properly for all the textFields) you can perform your operation in your `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method.

To get the value in the textField you can call the `intValue` method of the `text` property of the textField, i.e.

```
[[lastTextField text] intValue];
```

(the same way you can call `doubleValue`, `floatValue` and so on).
This way you can access the values in the textFields.

To update the final result you should call the `setText:` method of `totalTextField` (the method is the same if you want to update `totalLabel`). i.e. if you saved your result in a int called `res`, you can call

```
[totalTextField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", res]];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: you're a champion. Your time and expertise is appreciated greatly. I'm going to be testing this shortly and will update. Thank you.

Comment: what format or calculation would you suggest to sum the lowest 2 integers (of 3 available for selection)?

Comment: What method would you suggest to sum the lowest 2 of 3 integers located in UITextFields? Following is my code and 'IF Statements' are proving futile.

Comment: -(IBAction)calculate;
{int val = [month1.text intValue] + [month2.text intValue] + [month3.text intValue];    
 [result setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", val]];    
Which is working fine to sum 3 integers BUT I cannot figure out how to sum the 2 lowest. 'IF Statements' are proving futile. if ([month1.text intValue] > [month2.text intValue]) {
        int val = [month2.text intValue] + [month3.text intValue];

Comment: *NOTE: I changed the TextField Names to Month1,Month2,Month3 & Result if it appears confusing.

Comment: Figured it out:-(IBAction)calculate;     

{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int val;
    
    x = [month1.text intValue];
    y = [month2.text intValue];
    z = [month3.text intValue];
    
    val = (x+y+z) - MAX(x, MAX(y, z));
    NSString *String = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", val];
    result.text = String;
}  
    
    
   

-(IBAction) clear {
    month1.text = @"";
    month2.text = @"";
    month3.text = @"";
    result.text = @"";
    
}

Comment: Yes, that can be a simple solution :)